# Structure..can anyone figure this out?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Why does p->p1 produce 1, while s2.p1 produces 0? They both point to the exact same thing, and this does NOT happen with p->p2 and s2.p2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct S1{
    int p1, p2;
};
struct S2{
    int p1;
    struct S1 s1;
    int p2;
};

int main (void){
    int s = 0;
    struct S2 s2 = {1,2,3,0};
    struct S2 *p;
    p = (struct s2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));

    *p = s2;


    s2.p1 = 0;
    printf("p->p1 %d,s2.p1 %d   \n\n",p->p1, s2.p1 );
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",p->p1 , s2.p1 , p->p2 , p->s1.p2 );
    s = p->p1 + s2.p1 + p->p2 + p->s1.p2;

    free(p);
    printf("%d", s);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @WeatherVane And it's wrong.  See the problem? `p = (struct s2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));`

Comment: Anyways, `p->p1` is not the same as `s2.p1`.  `p` gets a copy of the contents of `s2`, but does not point to `s2`.

Comment: test.c(17): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 's2 *' to 'S2 *'.
test.c(24): warning C4473: 'printf' : not enough arguments passed for format string.
test.c(24): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 5 variadic arguments, but 4 were provided.
test.c(24): note: the missing variadic argument 5 is required by format string '%d'.

Comment: `.code.tio.c:17:7: warning: assignment to ‘struct S2 *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘struct s2 *’`  `.code.tio.c:24:34: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument`

Comment: "*They both point*" - no, they don't. `s2` is not a pointer.

Comment: s2 is storage class auto, allocated on the stack. p is allocated dynamically on the heap. They are two different chunks of memory. *p = s2 copies the contents of one to the other, but they are still different structures in different places.

Comment: Aside: Who or what text suggested the cast `(struct s2 *)` in `p = (struct s2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does p->p1 produce 1, ....?

Because code last assigned `p->p1` with the value of 1 with ****

```
//              v--- p1 member
struct S2 s2 = {1,2,3,0};
struct S2 *p;
p = (struct s2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));
*p = s2;  // ****  This copies the contents of `s2` to `*p`.
```

> Why does ... s2.p1 produces 0?

Because code *later* assigned 0 to `s2.p1` with

```
//              v--- p1 member
struct S2 s2 = {1,2,3,0};
...
s2.p1 = 0;
```

> They (`p->p1`,  `s2.p1`) both point to the exact same thing

No, they do not.  `p` is a pointer assigned with a value from allocated memory and `s2` is an object defined with `struct S2 s2`.  The allocated memory and the object `s2` are not the same location.  `s2` as a structure, never points to anything.  [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611904/structure-can-anyone-figure-this-out#comment88233928_50611904)

Answer (score 4):

Because you copied the contents of s2 into the structure pointed by p and then you updated s2 contents.